# Get list of roles assigned to an app registered inside Azure Active Directory - App Registrations

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Can you please help me know how I can get the roles which are assigned to an App under Azure Active Directory - App Registrations using `GraphServiceClient`? I can pass client id and client secrets to make a call to GraphAPI to get the roles assigned to it.

Comment: You are probably looking for this endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below in order to retrieve list of roles assigned by providing Service Principal ID.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var appRoleAssignedTo = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["{servicePrincipal-id}"].AppRoleAssignedTo
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

**REFERENCE:-**
[List appRoleAssignments granted to a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#http-request)

Also here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411587/retrieve-roles-and-users-per-application-in-microsoft-graph) that you can refer to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have another query. Suppose we have assigned Groups to Service Principle and groups have roles assigned.

How we can get roles which are assigned to Groups thru the service principle?